# Offline Mobile App data synchronization : what is the good way to maintain referential integrity

Tags: mobile, cordova, sencha-touch-2, data-synchronization

I am working on an offline mobile app.
It will allow user to synchronize newly added data to server.
In offline database (local database on mobile device) 3 tables are their.
In which say A tables can have many B - & B can have many C

A - B : 1 -  many & B - C : 1 - many.

& same structure in server db also.
Data can be added in offline mobile app & sync to server, 
even data can be added from a portal which will save data directly in a server database.

What is the best way to maintain referential integrity in that case :

On click of sync button in mobile app following has to happen -

downloading server data & inserting in local db, 
inserting new data & modifying existing data locally in offline app, 
syncing data to server(Upload modified & newly inserted data to server & download fresh data in device again).

what are the ways in which referential integrity can be maintained in offline mobile app. Are their any specific patterns  to follow in this case?

Comment: Your question is lost in the information. Be clear on what you are expecting?

Comment: what are the ways in which referential integrity can be maintained in offline mobile app when many tables are their. are their any specific patterns to follow in this case?

Comment: you are developing on android using sqlite as the solution for database?

Comment: yes using sencha touch with phonegap.